# Django Analytical Google Analytics Display Advertising working on development, staging but not production

Tags: django, google-analytics, analytical

Running Django 1.6 and Analytical 0.16.0

I have the following in my settings.py

```
GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_PROPERTY_ID = env_var('GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_PROPERTY_ID')
GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_DISPLAY_ADVERTISING = True
```

and the google analytics code shows up as expected when I run the site locally and on the staging server (ie. running the doubleclick dc.js analytics script), however when running on production it still shows the default Google Analytics ga.js script.

It isn't affected by `DEBUG` being on or off and as I can tell the settings and env are the same on production and staging servers (both runnning on Heroku). Can anyone offer an explanation of why this might be the case?

**edit**: **SOLVED**. Turns out I was still running Analytical 0.15.0 on the production server. I had wrongly assumed that heroku automatically installed the latest version if the version wasn't specified in the pip requirements.

Comment: Is it a caching issue?

Comment: Presumably not. It's been like this for weeks and doesn't change on a hard reset.

Answer (score 0):

Check that Heroku is running the same versions of each program:

```
   heroku pip freeze
```

It turns out it was still running an old version of django-analytical as the version number wasn't specified in the pip requirements file. Heroku won't upgrade an existing program unless explicitly specified. Changing the `requirements.txt` to the following solved it.

```
    django-analytical==0.16.0
```